# Jquery & vanilla javascript mixed, cart not reciving updated data [SOLVED]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, cart

to start I'm very new to code. Ive been stuck on this one problem for a week now and its killing me so i came here.

I want the h2 innerText of .item with the class of .item-selected to appear in cart once .cartadd is clicked

here's how I tired to do that:

```
let itemname = $('.item-selected h1').text();


    $('.cart').show()



      $('.cart').append('<h2>' + itemname + '</h2>');
```

When I do this I don't get anything though as if it didn't exist

when I console.log

```
let items = $(.item-selected) console.log(items)
```

I get log = Object { length: 0, prevObject: {…} }

I think the problem has to do with parts of the css being implemented by vanilla javascript and not jquery but not sure if that's the case or which part excatly.

heres that code

```
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownbox')
const dropdowns2 = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownbox2')
const itemboxQER = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

const shirtBox = document.querySelector('.shirtbox')
const hoodiebox = document.querySelector('.hoodiebox')
const sockbox = document.querySelector('.sockbox')
const pantbox = document.querySelector('.pantbox')
const underwearbox = document.querySelector('.underwearbox')
const stuffbox = document.querySelector('.stuffbox')
let selected;
//================CSS==========================






dropdowns.forEach(dropdown =>{
  const select = dropdown.querySelector('.select')
  const caret = dropdown.querySelector('.caret')
  const menu = dropdown.querySelector('.menu')
  const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('.menu li')
  selected = dropdown.querySelector('.selected')

  select.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    sel2.pause()
    sel2.currentTime = 0
    sel2.play()
    select.classList.toggle('select-clicked')
    caret.classList.toggle('caret-rotate')
    menu.classList.toggle('menu-open')
  }) 
  
  options.forEach(option =>{
    option.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      sel2.pause()
      sel2.currentTime = 0
      sel2.play()
      selected.innerText = option.innerText

      if (selected.innerText === "Shirts") {
        shirtBox.style.display = "block";
      } else { shirtBox.style.display = "none";}

      if(selected.innerText === "Socks")
      {
        sockbox.style.display = "block";
      } else {sockbox.style.display = "none";}

      if(selected.innerText === "Hoodies")
      {
        hoodiebox.style.display = "block";
      } else {hoodiebox.style.display = "none";}

      if(selected.innerText === "Pants")
      {
        pantbox.style.display = "block";
      } else {pantbox.style.display = "none";}

      if(selected.innerText === "Underwear")
      {
        underwearbox.style.display = "block";
      } else {underwearbox.style.display = "none";}

      if(selected.innerText === "Stuff & Things")
      {
        stuffbox.style.display = "block";
      } else {stuffbox.style.display = "none";}

      select.classList.remove('select-clicked')
      caret.classList.remove('caret-rotate')
      menu.classList.remove('menu-open')
      options.forEach(option =>{
        option.classList.add('active')
      }) 
    })
  })
})
//====================================================

dropdowns2.forEach(dropdown =>{
  const select2 = dropdown.querySelector('.select2')
  const caret2 = dropdown.querySelector('.caret2')
  const menu2 = dropdown.querySelector('.menu2')
  const options2 = dropdown.querySelectorAll('.menu2 li')
  const selected2 = dropdown.querySelector('.selected2')

  select2.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    sel2.pause()
    sel2.currentTime = 0
    sel2.play()
    select2.classList.toggle('select-clicked2')
    caret2.classList.toggle('caret-rotate2')
    menu2.classList.toggle('menu-open2')
  }) 
  
  options2.forEach(option =>{
    option.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      sel2.pause()
      sel2.currentTime = 0
      sel2.play()
      selected2.innerText = option.innerText
      
    
      
      select2.classList.remove('select-clicked2')
      caret2.classList.remove('caret-rotate2')
      menu2.classList.remove('menu-open2')
      options2.forEach(option =>{
        option.classList.add('active2')
      }) 
    })
  })
})
//====================================================
itemboxQER.forEach(item =>{

  item.addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
  
      itemboxQER.forEach(otherItem => {
        if (otherItem !== item) {
          otherItem.classList.remove('item-selected');
        }
      });

    item.classList.toggle('item-selected')
    sel2.pause()
    sel2.currentTime = 0
    sel2.play()
    })


  
  
  })
```

Any leads would be much appreciated!

relevant html (fixed duplicate id's, but same problem as they weren't used anyway)

```
          <div class="mainGUI" id="mainGUI">

      <button class="MIN" id="MIN">shrink/enlarge</button>

      <div class="dropdownbox" id="dropdownbox">
        <div class="select">
        <span class="selected" ><h1>SELECT CATEGORY </h1></span>
        <div class="caret"><img class="Icon" src="images/DOWNARROW.png" alt="broken"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
          <li class="Hoodies">Hoodies <img src="images/hoodie.png" alt=""></li>
          <li class="Shirts">Shirts <img src="images/shirt.png" alt=""></li>
          <li class="Pants">Pants <img src="images/pants.png" alt=""> </li>
          <li class="Underwear">Underwear <img src="images/under.png" alt=""></li>
          <li class="Socks">Socks <img src="images/socks.png" alt=""></li>
          <li class="StuffThings">Stuff & Things <img src="images/stuff.png" alt=""></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      




<!-- OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooMERCHOoooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO -->




<div class="shirtbox" id="shirtbox">
        

      <div class="item" id="freeshirt"><img src="images/shirttemp.png" alt="">
        
        <div class="itemHeaderBox">
          <h1>FREE PNG</h1>
          <div class="priceofitem">
            <h2>0$</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>

      <div class="item" id="rnbshirt"><img src="images/rnbbot.png" alt="">

        <div class="itemHeaderBox">
          <h1>RNB BOT SHIRT</h1>
          <div class="priceofitem">
            <h2>20$</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>

  </div>
<div class="hoodiebox" id="hoodiebox">
        
      <div class="item"><img src="images/hoodiloon.png" alt="">

        <div class="itemHeaderBox">
          <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
  </div>
<div class="sockbox" id="sockbox">
        
<!-- /////// -->
  <div class="item" id="item"><img src="./images/sock.png" alt="">

    <div class="itemHeaderBox">
      <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!-- /////// -->

        
<!-- /////// -->
  <div class="item" id="item"><img src="./images/sock.png" alt="">

    <div class="itemHeaderBox">
      <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!-- /////// -->

        
<!-- /////// -->
  <div class="item" id="item"><img src="./images/sock.png" alt="">

    <div class="itemHeaderBox">
      <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!-- /////// -->

        
<!-- /////// -->
  <div class="item" id="item"><img src="./images/sock.png" alt="">

    <div class="itemHeaderBox">
      <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!-- /////// -->

        
<!-- /////// -->
  <div class="item" id="item"><img src="./images/sock.png" alt="">

    <div class="itemHeaderBox">
      <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!-- /////// -->

        
<!-- /////// -->
  <div class="item" id="item"><img src="./images/sock.png" alt="">

    <div class="itemHeaderBox">
      <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!-- /////// -->


      
  </div>
<div class="pantbox" id="pantbox">
        

      <div class="item"><img src="images/pantaloon.png" alt="">

        <div class="itemHeaderBox">
          <h1>FREE SHIRT PNG</h1>
        </div>
        
      </div>
  
  </div>
<div class="underwearbox" id="underwearbox">
        
      <div class="item"><img src="images/underiloon.png" alt="">

        <div class="itemHeaderBox">
          <h1>thong</h1>
        </div>
        
      </div>
     
  </div>
<div class="stuffbox" id="stuffbox">
        
      <div class="item" ><img src="images/catstuff.png" alt="">

        <div class="itemHeaderBox">
          <h1>cat</h1>
        </div>
        
      </div>
     
  </div>
  <!-- OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooMERCHOoooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO -->


<!-- =======================================size/color================================================ -->
      <div class="dropdownbox2" id="dropdownsize">
        <div class="select2">
        <span class="selected2" id="selectedSize" ><h1>size</h1></span>
        <div class="caret2"><img class="Icon2" src="images/DOWNARROW.png" alt="broken"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu2" id="sizemenu">
          <li class="small">small</li>
          <li class="medium">medium</li>
          <li class="large">large</li>
          <li class="X-large">X-large</li>
          <li class="XX-large">XX-large</li>
          <li class="XXX-large">XXX-large</li> 
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdownbox2" id="dropdowncolor">
        <div class="select2">
        <span class="selected2" id="selectedSize" ><h1>color</h1></span>
        <div class="caret2"><img class="Icon2" src="images/DOWNARROW.png" alt="broken"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu2" id="colormenu">
          <li class="white">white</li>
          <li class="black">black</li>
          <li class="pink">pink</li>
          <li class="red">red</li>
          <li class="blue">blue</li>
          <li class="green">green</li> 
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="cartadd" id="cartadd">Add to Cart</div>

      <div class="cart" id="cart">
        <div class="carttitle">CART</div>
      </div>

      <div class="done" id="done">DONE</div>

  </div>
```

update, so the problem was a mix of jquery not detecting the change because the change was made in vanilla javascript & the check for .item-selected needed to be made a function and checked every frame:

```
  function SELECTCHECK(){
  $('.item').each(function() {


if ($(this).hasClass('item item-selected')) {
  
  itemprice = $(this).find('h2').text();
}

})}
```

and the animation

```
  function TICK(timestamp) {
 
  requestAnimationFrame(TICK)

  SELECTCHECK()
}
requestAnimationFrame(TICK)
```

hopefully this can help someone in the future. Rule of thumb, DONT't mix jquery event listeners with vanilla javascript event listeners.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well? Just the relevant parts.

Comment: no problem, added it to main question

Comment: Some of the ids seem to appear more than once. They should be unique. Check the `id="item"` and the `id="dropdownbox2"`.

Comment: in the html id="dropdownbox2"  id="item" are used multiple times cause I want them  to be effected in the css and javascript in the same way, that part i think should be fine

Comment: No, that's invalid syntax. If you're doing that just because of CSS, add a class, and target them by the class.

Comment: ah nevermind i can see why that makes sense, but im not really using the duplicated ids so i dont think thats my problem but good tip